# Spring boot/ Hibernate application problems with multiple databases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Attempting to make a application with multiple databases but apparently I'm doing something terribly wrong. Sorry if something I wrote below is stupid, but since I've started coding it won't be my first time. Note I'm using multiple schemas. Not sure if this is the correct way to write an app like this with multiple databases.

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buyers",schema = "toner_buyer")
public class Buyers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "BUYER_ID")
    private int buyerId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "BUYER_ADDRESS")
    private String buyerAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANG_ID")
    private Manager manager;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Toner.class, mappedBy = "buyers",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Toner> toners;

    public Buyers(){}

    public Buyers(String firstName, String lastName, String buyerAddress, Set<Toner> buyerToner) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
        this.toners = buyerToner;
    }

    public int getBuyerId() {
        return buyerId;
    }

    public void setBuyerId(int buyerId) {
        this.buyerId = buyerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getBuyerAddress() {
        return buyerAddress;
    }

    public void setBuyerAddress(String buyerAddress) {
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
    }

    public Set<Toner> getBuyerToner() {
        return toners;
    }

    public void setBuyerToner(Set<Toner> buyerToner) {
        this.toners = buyerToner;
    }
}
```

2nd:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "managers", schema = "toner_manager")
public class Manager {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MANG_ID")
    private int mid;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private System lastName;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Buyers.class, mappedBy = "managers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Buyers> buyers;
}
```

3rd:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "toners",schema = "toner_stock")
public class Toner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TONER_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "TONER_NAME")
    private String tonerName;

    @Column(name = "TONER_PRICE")
    private int tonerPrice;

    @Column(name = "TONER_QUANTITY")
    private int tonerQuantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUYER_ID")
    private Buyers buyers;

    public Toner(){}

    public Toner(int tonerId){
        this.id = tonerId;
    }

    public Toner(String tonerName, int tonerPrice, int tonerQuantity) {
        this.tonerName = tonerName;
        this.tonerPrice = tonerPrice;
        this.tonerQuantity = tonerQuantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Toner{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", tonerName='" + tonerName + '\'' +
                ", tonerPrice=" + tonerPrice +
                ", tonerQuantity=" + tonerQuantity +
                '}';
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTonerName() {
        return tonerName;
    }

    public void setTonerName(String tonerName) {
        this.tonerName = tonerName;
    }

    public int getTonerPrice() {
        return tonerPrice;
    }

    public void setTonerPrice(int tonerPrice) {
        this.tonerPrice = tonerPrice;
    }

    public int getTonerQuantity() {
        return tonerQuantity;
    }

    public void setTonerQuantity(int tonerQuantity) {
        this.tonerQuantity = tonerQuantity;
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.ds_toner.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_stock?useSSL=false
spring.ds_toner.username=toner
spring.ds_toner.password=toner
spring.ds_toner.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.ds_manager.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_manager?useSSL=false
spring.ds_manager.username=toner
spring.ds_manager.password=toner
spring.ds_manager.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.ds_buyer.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_buyer?useSSL=false
spring.ds_buyer.username=toner
spring.ds_buyer.password=toner
spring.ds_buyer.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Print trace:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50343:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock/target/classes:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.11/logback-core-1.1.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.24/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.24/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.7/jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.7/jackson-core-2.8.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.4.0/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.9/groovy-2.4.9.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.1.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.24/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.24/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.11/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.11/tomcat-juli-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.1.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.6.6/byte-buddy-1.6.6.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/3.0.3.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring3-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronaldpitt/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar com.ronone.Application
objc[705]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10a2ef4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10a3b74e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-05-12 21:48:45.407  INFO 705 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 705 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock)
2017-05-12 21:48:45.411  INFO 705 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-12 21:48:45.661  INFO 705 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Fri May 12 21:48:45 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-12 21:48:47.203  INFO 705 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd5e7927] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-12 21:48:47.646  INFO 705 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-12 21:48:47.670  INFO 705 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-12 21:48:47.671  INFO 705 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-05-12 21:48:47.821  INFO 705 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-12 21:48:47.821  INFO 705 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2164 ms
2017-05-12 21:48:48.029  INFO 705 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-12 21:48:48.035  INFO 705 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-12 21:48:48.036  INFO 705 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-12 21:48:48.036  INFO 705 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-12 21:48:48.036  INFO 705 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-12 21:48:48.955  INFO 705 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-12 21:48:48.985  INFO 705 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-12 21:48:49.118  INFO 705 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
2017-05-12 21:48:49.120  INFO 705 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-12 21:48:49.302  INFO 705 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-12 21:48:49.441  INFO 705 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-05-12 21:48:49.709  WARN 705 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.ronone.entities.Buyers.managers in com.ronone.entities.Manager.buyers
2017-05-12 21:48:49.716  INFO 705 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-12 21:48:49.735  INFO 705 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-12 21:48:49.745 ERROR 705 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.ronone.entities.Buyers.managers in com.ronone.entities.Manager.buyers
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ronone.Application.main(Application.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.ronone.entities.Buyers.managers in com.ronone.entities.Manager.buyers
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mappedBy` value is incorrect.  In your `Manager` class, make the following change:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Buyers.class, mappedBy = "manager", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Buyers> buyers;
```

The reason your code failed was because the `ManyToOne` it should point to is called `manager` and not called `managers`.